# Is there a method onChildAdded in Firestore like it is in firebase real time?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Do firestore support `(add document listener)` like `firebase real time`

*firebase real time has the method like this*

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}
```

But I'm not sure if there is such method in firestore , I want it to notify me when add new document inside the collection , I am using java.

Comment: added tags to gain more attention and wordings for betterment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can on onSnapshot to get a callback for new and changed documents, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Comment: I have already checked that page but there is many methods in that page so I'm not sure who is will give me what I want.

Comment: That page is all about onSnapshot.

Comment: I know that but I saw I should write document name for listener it but I don't know what's document name because I need notify me when add new document.